# Null pointer exception error that I am having trouble figuring out?

Tags: java, swing

I can't figure out how to fix my null pointer. My holder (Holder Pattern class) is undefined - I'm not sure how to fix it. I am still pretty new to programming. Thanks for any ideas on how to go about fixing this!

```
public Goose (JPanel container, GooseBehavior behavior, BehaviorHolder holder) {
    super(container); 
    _holder = holder;
    double rnd = Math.random(); //local variable to create random angle
    //System.out.println(rnd);
    this.setRotation(rnd);//sets the rotation angle to a random angle
    this.setSize(25, 20); //sets size 
    this.setFillColor(java.awt.Color.RED); //sets color 
    this.setWrapping(true); //sets wrapping to true
    _gooseBehavior = behavior; //stores _gooseehavior
    _gooseBehavior = _holder.getBehavior();
}

public void react() {
    _gooseBehavior.stop(); //tells the current _gooseBehavior to stop
    _holder.getBehavior(); //gets the stored behavior from the holder
    _gooseBehavior = _holder.getBehavior(); //sets the new value to one stored in holder
    _gooseBehavior.setTarget(this); //sets the target on goose
    _gooseBehavior.start(); //starts the behavior

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Animal.Goose.<init>(Bee.java:26)
at Animal.DrawingPanel.<init>(DrawingPanel.java:30)
at Animal.ControlPanel.<init>(ControlPanel.java:27)
at Animal.App.<init>(App.java:28)
at Animal.App.main(App.java:39)
```

Here's the code where I instantiate BehaviorHolder in my Control Panel (top level object), and then I just have it stored in my drawingPanel, Goose class, and BehaviorButtons so that its associated with the three.

```
public ControlPanel() {
    super();
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());//sets a new BorderLayout
    _drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(_holder); 
    _moveRandomly = new MoveBehavior();
    _doNothing = new StopBehavior();
    _kingGoose = new FollowBehavior(_kingGoose);
    _holder = new BehaviorHolder(_moveBehavior);
```

Comment: Which line do you get the NPE (NullPointerException) on?

Comment: I get it on _gooseBehavior = _holder.getBehavior();

Comment: I'm guessing you're passing in a `null` to the constructor. Check the place where you create `Goose` and see if what you're passing in for `holder` is actually initialized to an instance of `BehaviorHolder`.

Comment: Sorry...I am not sure what the stack trace is?

Comment: Sussie, do something like: `try { _gooseBehavior = _holder.getBehavior(); } catch (NullPointerException npe) { npe.printStackTrace(); }` . It will catch the exception, and print the stack trace. Then analyse the output - it will give you clues where is the problem.

Comment: @Susie When you encounter an exception like this that isn't handled (caught), you should see a lot of lines after the one that shows you the exception in the output. Could be the DOS or Unix shell, or your IDE output window (Eclipse, NetBeans), depending on how you've started your application. That's the stacktrace. It shows a path to the exact location of where the exception originated and how the program got there (method call stack).

Comment: BehaviorHolder might be coming in as null in your constructor.

Comment: Oh! Okay...here is the stack trace that shows up when I try to run the program:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Animal.Goose.<init>(Bee.java:26)
 at Animal.DrawingPanel.<init>(DrawingPanel.java:30)
 at Animal.ControlPanel.<init>(ControlPanel.java:27)
 at Animal.App.<init>(App.java:28)
 at Animal.App.main(App.java:39)

Comment: @Susie Edit your original question to add the stack trace in. Type something like "EDIT: here's the stacktrace" after your code block and then paste the stack trace in the same manner as code (using indentation to make it formatted like a code block). You might also have to provide some pieces of `Animal.DrawingPanel`, probably the constructor. It's likely that's the one which needs to make a `BehaviorHolder` but doesn't do it. Unless it gets it from "above" itself.

Comment: ? duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003049/beginner-programmer-can-someone-help-me-figure-out-my-null-pointer-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to say without a stack trace and incomplete code example, but there's multiple potential problems with your code:

```
public Goose (JPanel container, GooseBehavior behavior, BehaviorHolder holder) {
    super(container); 

    // removed some code for clarity

    _gooseBehavior = behavior;                     // <<- You store behaviour here
    _gooseBehavior = _holder.getBehavior();        // <<- then immediately override it
}

public void react() {
    _gooseBehavior.stop();
    _holder.getBehavior();                  // <-- this isn't getting assigned to anything
    _gooseBehavior = _holder.getBehavior(); // A duplicate assignment, previously done in constructor. Are you changing holder's behaviour outside of the display class?

    _gooseBehavior.setTarget(this); //sets the target on goose
    _gooseBehavior.start(); //starts the behavior    
}
```

I would guess `_gooseBehaviour` is null, but you can help us answer your question if you include the full stack trace (The error that was printed out that let you know you had a null pointer exception).

***EDIT***

Based off your NPE I'll bet dollar's to donuts that your holder is getting passed into the constructor as a null. Inspect it's value in your debugger or print out its value to verify.

Comment: +1, well spotted. Didn't see there was another line that did the same thing.

Comment: Thanks!! I will take a look at it. Sorry - how do you inspect a value in the debugger? I just started using Eclipse (or an IDE in general) last week so I am still learning.

Comment: I don't want to post run-on sentences describing how to set breakpoints etc etc, so I'll point you towards these video tutorials instead. They can be extremely helpful - http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/debugger.html.

Comment: Okay....from what I got from the debugger, it is saying the value of my _gooseBehavior is null.

Answer (score 0):

It can help to explicitly validate the constructor/method parameters, and throw a more informative exception if there's something wrong:

```
if (behavior == null)
    throw new NullPointerException("behavior is null");
if (holder == null)
    throw new NullPointerException("holder is null");
```

That way:

1. If the problem is a null parameter you'll immediately not only know that it's a parameter problem, but which parameter is the problem.
2. If you get a `NullPointerException` without any added info you know immediately that the problem isn't a null parameter.

Then you can add further validation of the parameters once you know they aren't `null`:

```
if (holder.getBehavior() == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("holder's behavior is null");
```