# Getting a NullPointerException in my Swing Goose class

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I think my `_holder` and/or `_gooseAction` is `null`.... Here are the relevant code/classes where `_holder` and `_gooseAction` are instantiated:

#### Goose.java

```
public class Goose {
    //Goose class
    private ActionHolder _holder;
    private gooseAction _gooseAction;

    public Goose (JPanel container, GooseAction action, ActionHolder holder) {
        super(container); 
        _holder = holder;
        _gooseAction = _holder.getAction();
        _gooseAction = action;  
    }

    public void react() {
        _gooseAction.stop(); 
        _holder.getAction(); 
        _gooseAction = _holder.getAction(); 
        _gooseAction.setObjective(this); 
        _gooseAction.start();   
    }
```

#### ControlPanel.java

```
public class ControlPanel {
    //top level class
    public ControlPanel() { 
         super();
        _holder = new ActionHolder(_moveAction);
          _drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(_holder); 
         _gooseAction = new GooseAction();
         _doNothing = new StopBehavior();
         _kingGoose = new FollowBehavior(_kingGoose);
    } 

    private GooseAction _gooseAction;
    private ActionHolder _holder;

    public class ActionHolder {
        private GooseAction _GooseAction;
        public ActionHolder(GooseAction Action) {
            _gooseAction = Action;
        }
        public void setAction(GooseAction GooseAction) {
            _gooseAction = GooseAction;
        }
        public GooseAction getAction() {
            return _gooseAction.copy();
        }
    }

public class ActionButton extends JButton {
    public ActionButton(String string, boolean b, GooseAction action, ActionHolder holder) {
        super(string, b);
        _holder = holder;
        _gooseAction = action;

    }
}

private class ActionListener implements ChangeListener {
    
    public ActionListener(GooseAction action) { 
    }

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        _holder.setAction(_gooseAction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code raises the exception?

Comment: Did you already use a debugger to find out where it breaks and what local variables are in your scope at that moment?

Comment: What's the exception you're getting? Let's see the stack trace of it.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?  Also note that you are assigning _holder.getAction() to _gooseAction in the constructor and then immediately assigning action to it, overriding the previous reference.

Comment: This is the stacktrace - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Swarm.Bee.react(Bee.java:30)
 at Swarm.DrawingPanel$BeeListener.mouseClicked(DrawingPanel.java:72)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6291)

Comment: and the exception is in the react() in Goose class _gooseAction.stop()

Comment: ? duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001645/null-pointer-exception-error-that-i-am-having-trouble-figuring-out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(_holder == null) System.out.println("_holder is null");
if(_gooseAction == null) System.out.println("_gooseAction is null");
```

Comment: While I hope you post some more explanation about this, this is a good place to start, especially if skills with a debugger are lacking.

Comment: They were both null. I figured out the _holder but not the Action